# git push commits to pr and discussion

Tags: git, github

I made a pr (says branchX) to master. But then my teammate is giving feedback. My other teammate is trying to help, should he create another branch or just push directly to the branchX? if he create another branch it will make the conversation discontinue in github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you (or your teammate) from simply making one or more additional commits, and then pushing the feature branch to GitHub again.  In that case, GitHub would automatically update the pull request with the latest changes, and the reviewer could take those changes into account.

Comment: cool, there's no need to create a new branch for this right.

Comment: Not unless the change is so significant that it might merit an entirely separate branch from your feature branch, which I would say is unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do any number of things:

- You incorporate ideas from the discussion  into a commit on this branch and push it
- Someone else incorporates ideas into a commit on this branch and pushes it (usually regarded as rude, but not forbidden)
- Someone else branches from your branch, makes a commit and pushes it, and offers it to you as a pull request into your pull request
- Someone makes actual Suggestions (a formal term); those that you accept are formed into a commit for you, so it’s like someone helping you write your code

And many other possibilities.

Comment: `Someone else branches from your branch, makes a commit and pushes it, and offers it to you as a pull request into your pull request`

^ how to do this? pr into a pr which haven't been approve? does github automatically handle that?

Comment: how does that beneficial compare to someone directly push to the branch? if the pr is merged, what happens to the pr of pr? it will be merged too?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. If it was merged, it was merged. If it wasn't, it wasn't.